# Can I force an ASP.NET web app to pool or reuse connections without changing the code or connection string?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-applications

I have a web server with a legacy VB.NET/ASP.NET web app on it, and normal use of the app results in thousands of connections to the database server, all in series - open connection, execute really simple query that returns instantly, close connection, repeat. The ORM (custom-developed) is extremely inefficient and is the cause of these thousands of queries, but it's not something I can change in the app. The app also has the connection string hard-coded (though I can change the username and password from a config file).

The volume is so high that the SQL Server instance the app uses has to be on the same VM - even moving it to another VM on the same host can introduce timeouts or other user issues.

**Without changing the code or the connection string itself, is there any way I can force the app to reuse connections or pool the connections, reducing the number it has to make?** It's an ASP.NET 2.0 application, though it's running with SQL 2016 on a Windows 2016 Server, so maybe there's a new option in those somewhere.

Comment: Does the Connection String turn off Connection Pooling?  It's on by default.

Comment: I don't think it explicitly turns it off, but if I use SQL Profiler, I see it continuously opening and closing connections, hundreds of times a minute. I'll check and see if I can confirm the connection string.

Comment: What's the EventSubclass of the Audit:Login event?  If it's 2, then the event is generated just to track the reuse of a pooled connection.  Not the creation of a new connection.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/audit-login-event-class?view=sql-server-ver15